# Maven tests run locally but fail in github action

Tags: maven, github-actions

I'm trying to run the basic maven java action listed [here](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/ci/maven.yml) on my repo here: https://github.com/dhowe/rita2/

The `mvn -B package --file pom.xml` cmd runs correctly in my local repo, but the tests fails in the github action with the following error (full log [here](https://github.com/dhowe/rita2/runs/1363673661?check_suite_focus=true)):

```
Exception: Cannot load dictionary at rita_dict.js /home/runner/work/rita2/rita2
```

So its clear that the dictionary resource is not being found when run via the github action. But why would the file (src/main/java/rita_dict.js) be found by maven locally, but not when run in the action ?

Comment: did you consider to move src/main/java/rita_dict.js under /src/main/resources?

Comment: I did consider that, but I'd still like to know what the issue is here, and what is different about the environment on github actions

Answer (score 1):

Switched to specifying the resource in /src/main/resources as suggested by P3trur0 (not sure why it wasn't working when specified as a resource in maven) after which builds work as expected